# Why the picture in data doesn't show in v-card? (Vuetify)

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

The picture doesn't show in v-card but other data can still show in label. The picture data is image links. For example, {name: 'Kitty Doll', points: 1000, amount: 4, picture: "http://f.lnwfile.com/7mgmwg.png"}

I can't upload the picture to this,so I put it in this link https://i.stack.imgur.com/JlVuL.jpg

```
            <v-card class="mb-2" tile='' height="200" width="200">
              <v-row align="start">
                    <v-col class="shrink">
                         <v-img src= item.picture></v-img>
                    </v-col>
                 </v-row>
            </v-card>
          
        
          <br>
          <label for="name">Name: <td>{{ item.name }}</td> </label>
           <br>
          <label for="points">Points: <td>{{ item.points }}</td></label>
           <br>
           <label for="amount">Amount: <td>{{ item.amount }}</td> </label>
         


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/xoh8p.png
```

Comment: Please create a [mcve]

Comment: `<v-img :src= "item.picture"></v-img>` 
HTML Attribute should be quoted, and if it is javascript variable, use `:src` instead of `src`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bind it as follows :

```
<v-img :src="item.picture"></v-img>
```